# Integral of gaussian and sine/cosine

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I really need the solution of two integrals involving exponentials and sine/cosine.

- For $n\in \mathbf{N}$ even :
  $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{2\,ax\sin(\pi ax)}{\pi\left(a^2x^2-(n/2)^2\right)}\right)^2\quad \exp(-bx^2)\quad dx$$
- while for $n\in \mathbf{N}$ odd :
  $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{2\,ax\cos(\pi ax)}{\pi\left(a^2x^2-(n/2)^2\right)}\right)^2\quad \exp(-bx^2)\quad dx$$

with $a>0$ and $b>0$.

Thanks